# Renaming files with random string after upload and storing the name in array

Tags: php, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I'm trying to process multiple files upload with `foreach` then rename the files with random string and store the file names in an array, here's my current code:

```
    // this variable stores the id of last inserted row in MySQLi DB
    $last_shipment_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    // Array of valid file formats
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
    // the upload path
    $path = "../uploads/"; // Upload directory
    // count variable for foreach counting
    $count = 0;
    // variable for generated file names to use them later
    $new_file_name = array();


    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_file_name[] = randomNumber(14)."-".$last_shipment_id.'.'.$ext;

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue;
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue;
            } else {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$new_file_name)) {

                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

I can't find where the problem is, should I use `foreach` for every generated file name then use `move_uploaded_file` inside the `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely wrong. You have initialized `$_FILES['files']['name']` in the `foreach` statement and trying to access `$_FILES['files']['error']` and `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]` in each iteration. Since this is an array it not possible.

So solution is as follows,

```
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$row){
   $ext = pathinfo($row[$key]['files']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $new_file = randomNumber(14)."-".$last_shipment_id.'.'.$ext;
    array_push($new_file_name,$new_file);
    if ($row[$key]['files']['error'] == 4) {
        continue;
    }          
    if ($row[$key]['files']['error'] == 0) {              
        if( ! in_array($ext,  $valid_formats) ){
           $error_msg = "The file ". $new_file. " is not a valid format";
           array_push($message, $error_msg); 
            continue;
        } else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($row[$key]["files"]["tmp_name"], $path.$new_file_name[$key])) {

            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.